# AngularJS ngView not working when app deployed on server

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am using ngView of angularJS in one of my application. But it works fine on my localsystem but not working on my server.There are various views like HomeScreen,DeviceRegistration etc. When i click on HomeScreen then its related view should be shown in the div with attribute ng-view.

Below is the code for html:

```
<body ng-controller="TrackingSystemCtrl">
<div class="mainDiv">
    Choose:
    <a href="HomeScreen">HomeScreen</a>
    <a href="DeviceRegistration">DeviceRegistration</a> |
    <a href="RegistrationInfo">RegistrationInfo</a> |
    <a href="TrackerScreen">TrackerScreen</a>
    <a href="AvailableDeviceList">AvailableDeviceList</a> |
    <a href="FriendInfo">FriendInfo</a>
    <a href="AvailableDeviceList">AvailableDeviceList</a> |


    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Below is the code for controller:

```
    angular.module('trackingSystem', [], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/AvailableDeviceList', {
        templateUrl: 'views/AvailableDeviceList.html',
        controller: AvailableDeviceListCtrl
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/DeviceRegistration', {
        templateUrl: 'views/DeviceRegistration.html',
        controller: DeviceRegistrationCtrl
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/FriendInfo', {
        templateUrl: 'http://webesperto.com/trackingsystemapp/views/FriendInfo.html',
        controller: FriendInfoCtrl
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/HomeScreen', {
        templateUrl: 'http://webesperto.com/trackingsystemapp/views/HomeScreen.html',
        controller: HomeScreenCtrl
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/RegistrationInfo', {
        templateUrl: 'http://webesperto.com/trackingsystemapp/views/RegistrationInfo.html',
        controller: RegistrationInfoCtrl
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/TrackerScreen', {
        templateUrl: 'views/TrackerScreen.html',
        controller: TrackerScreenCtrl
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

function TrackingSystemCtrl($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location)
{
    $scope.$route = $route;
    $scope.$location = $location;
    $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;

    $scope.isRegistered = false;

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
    console.log("view changed    " + angular.toJson(event));
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there is any problem in the question..?

Comment: Yes, you can't simply point to your site and tell us a problem. Post the relevant code (probably your route controller), and any errors in the console (if any). Also, explain what "not working" means, thanks.

Comment: okz, i am going to change my post...thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link:

```
<a href="#/Hello">Hello</a>
```

Routes:

```
$routeProvider.when('/Hello', {
        templateUrl: 'views/Hello.html',
        controller: 'HelloCtrl'
      })
```

Comment: Edited to make answer more specific. Could you check console for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Put a forward slash (/) in the href like this:

```
<a href="/HomeScreen">HomeScreen</a>
```

Comment: Actually there is an another problem i think.Let's take a domain name like www.abc.com and i have an app in this domain name myApp. So the link of the domain is www.abc.com/myApp. Now if i have to give the path of the view which is placed in views folder of myApp what i have to give. I gave templateUrl : 'views/pqr.html'.